# Render multi-track audio

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, audio

How to render with multi-track audio and offset? Setting the "mono" option in each sound strip results in using first two tracks without offset and silence on remaining two.

The audio must be AAC, 4 channels. Each of the audio tracks may be a different file.

| Video sequencer (VSE) | Audio settings | Rendered |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: vse] | [image: audio settings] | [image: rendered] |

In the rendered, I expect the audio to be offset depending on offset in VSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The channels in the Video Editor do not correspond to any audio channel in the final downmix.

What you can do is, select your audio strip, enable the Mono option in the sidebar > Strip tab > Sound panel.

Then you can play with the Pan value:

[image: pan]

Sound Strip's pan: [Strip — Sound: Pan](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.4/editors/video_sequencer/sequencer/sidebar/strip.html#bpy-types-soundsequence-pan)

> Used to pan the audio between speakers in multichannel audio. Only works for mono sources. The number of audio channels can be configured in the Audio Output settings.
>
> For stereo output panning works from left (-1) to right (1). When the output uses more than two channels, values can be between -2 and 2, where 0 means front/center, -1 means to the left and 1 to the right.
>
> To address rear speakers, you can pan to those with the higher values: -2, 2 is back. This value basically represents the angle at which it’s played if you multiply the value by 90 degrees.
>
> For smooth animation you can assign values outside the soft bounds, since the angle wraps around over multiple rotations.

Comment: @xgjxcxzk Oh, you found the manual entry for _Pan_, thanks for editing it in. I was just about to do the same, saved me some work :)

Comment: Love it when we tag-team answers 